# Have user register and accept invitation together on Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Currently on Laravel Jetstream, if a user doesn't exist, you are able to send an invitation for them to register and then accept the invite to your team. But the process to do this is the user clicks on Register in the email, and then has to go back to the email and click accept invitation. Is there a way to have them register and not have to go back to the email but after registration, it also accepts the invite to the team?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create the hasteam middle ware as described here: https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/117

Then edit the handle method to be:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (Auth::user()->currentTeam->count() === 0) {
            //check to see if there is a pending invite.
            $invitation = TeamInvitation::where('email', '=', Auth::user()->email)->first();
            if ($invitation) {
                app(AddsTeamMembers::class)->add(
                    $invitation->team->owner,
                    $invitation->team,
                    $invitation->email,
                    $invitation->role
                );

                $invitation->delete();
                return redirect(config('fortify.home'))->banner(
                    __('Great! You have accepted the invitation to join the :team team.', ['team' => $invitation->team->name]),
                );
            }else{
                return Response(view('no-team'));
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```